# How to copy parquet file from AWS s3 bucket to a snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to move a parquet file from S3 bucket to snowflake table and following [this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Upload-Data-from-AWS-s3-to-Snowflake-in-a-Simple-Way) article.

I am able to create a stage area using this from snowflake CLI from LINUX server:

```
user_id#WAREHOUSE_NAME@DATABASE_NAME.PUBLIC> CREATE OR REPLACE stage STAGE_NAME
                                 file_format = (type='parquet')
                                 url = 's3://bucket_name/file_name.parquet' credentials = (aws_key_id='99ZZ' aws_secret_key='99ZZ99ZZ99ZZ');
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| status                                                           |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Stage area STAGE_NAME successfully created.                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.499s
```

But when I try to SELECT from here I can't see any data:

```
user_id#WAREHOUSE_NAME@DATABASE_NAME.PUBLIC>LIST @STAGE_NAME;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
| name                                                                                           |   size | md5                              | last_modified                |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------------|
| s3://bucket_name/file_name.parquet                                                             | 190112 | 9chk2354klfkasjla375902850asfhak | Mon, 3 Jan 2022 16:54:08 GMT |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.508s


user_id#WAREHOUSE_NAME@DATABASE_NAME.PUBLIC>SELECT $1:col_1::BIGINT, $1:col_2::VARCHAR(100), $1:col_3::TIMESTAMP, $1:col_4::VARCHAR(10), $1:col_5::DATE, $1:col_6::BIGINT, $1:col_7::TIMESTAMP, $1:col_8::VARCHAR FROM @STAGE_NAME;
+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------+------------+-------------+
| $1:col_1  | $1:col_2  | $1:col_3    | $1:col_4      | $1:col_5  | $1:col_6               | $1:col_7   | $1:col_8    |
|-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------+------------+-------------|
| NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL          | NULL      | NULL                   | NULL       | NULL        |
.
.
| NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL          | NULL      | NULL                   | NULL       | NULL        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------+------------+-------------+
2000 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 1.457s
```

There are 2000 rows with NULL and I know there should be 2000 rows. So at least number of rows are correct but can't select the data.

**Sample row from `file_name.csv` file which is converted to parquet:**

```
col_1           col_2                                   col_3                           col_4   col_5           col_6           col_7                           col_8
130168850       MODERATE_SEVERITY_OUTAGE_DECLARE        2021-11-15 23:41:16.000000      EST     2021-11-15      20211116        2021-11-21 15:29:17.000000      {"OutgSk":99999999,"DimOrgBlgFTAHistSk":279008,"DimStitchOutgSvrtySk":3,"DclrDflctDur":1,"DclrRslvDur":6883,"OutgDur":6883,"GapDur":0,"MaintTmFl":0,"AmbshCallDclrCnt":0,"OffrCallDclrCnt":0,"HndlCallDclrCnt":0,"UniqDclrCnt":0,"DclrCnt":0,"TrkRollPendDclrCnt":0,"TrkRollCnclDclrCnt":0,"TrkRollCmpltDclrCnt":0,"NtrlDistrFl":0,"OutgStartDttmEST":"2021-11-15 20:41:16","OutgDclrDttmEST":"2021-11-15 23:41:16","OutgDflctDttmEST":"2021-11-15 23:41:17","OutgRslvDttmEST":"2021-11-16 01:35:59","OutgEndDttmEST":"2021-11-16 04:35:59","StitchOutgSvrtyRnk":3}
```

**Question:** What am I missing here?
If there is any other way to copy parquet file from s3 bucket into snowflake then please share that information. That would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1:**
When I do `SELECT $1 FROM @STAGE_NAME;` I get 2000 rows in result. This is first row from result:

```
$1 
"{
  ""col_1\tcol_2\tcol_3\tcol_4\tcol_5\tcol_6\tcol_7\tcol_8"": ""StitchOutgSvrtyRnk:3}"",
  ""__index_level_0__"": ""130168850\tMODERATE_SEVERITY_OUTAGE_DECLARE\t2021-11-15 23:41:16.000000\tEST\t2021-11-15\t20211116\t2021-11-21 15:29:17.000000\t{\""DimStitchOutgSk\"":69330243"",
  ""__index_level_10__"": ""OffrCallDclrCnt:0"",
  ""__index_level_11__"": ""HndlCallDclrCnt:0"",
  ""__index_level_12__"": ""UniqOffrCallDclrCnt:0"",
  ""__index_level_13__"": ""TrkRollDclrCnt:0"",
  ""__index_level_14__"": ""TrkRollPendDclrCnt:0"",
  ""__index_level_15__"": ""TrkRollCnclDclrCnt:0"",
  ""__index_level_16__"": ""TrkRollCmpltDclrCnt:0"",
  ""__index_level_17__"": ""NtrlDistrFl:0"",
  ""__index_level_18__"": ""OutgStartDttmEST:\""2021-11-15 20:41:16\"""",
  ""__index_level_19__"": ""OutgDclrDttmEST:\""2021-11-15 23:41:16\"""",
  ""__index_level_1__"": ""DimOrgBlgFTAHistSk:279008"",
  ""__index_level_20__"": ""OutgDflctDttmEST:\""2021-11-15 23:41:17\"""",
  ""__index_level_21__"": ""OutgRslvDttmEST:\""2021-11-16 01:35:59\"""",
  ""__index_level_22__"": ""OutgEndDttmEST:\""2021-11-16 04:35:59\"""",
  ""__index_level_2__"": ""DimStitchOutgSvrtySk:3"",
  ""__index_level_3__"": ""DclrDflctDur:1"",
  ""__index_level_4__"": ""DclrRslvDur:6883"",
  ""__index_level_5__"": ""OutgDur:6883"",
  ""__index_level_6__"": ""GapDur:0"",
  ""__index_level_7__"": ""PrimetimeFl:1"",
  ""__index_level_8__"": ""MaintTmFl:0"",
  ""__index_level_9__"": ""AmbshCallDclrCnt:0""
}"
```

Does the format of parquet look right? If format is correct then how can I form my `SELECT ...` to to retrieve data in `col_1, col_2, .., col_8`?

Comment: Do you have a sample record from the parquet file that you could include in your post?  It seems like perhaps Snowflake isn't finding the attributes with the column names that you are giving it.  Remember that attributes are case-sensitive when reading from semi-structured data.  So, is `col_1` etc. the correct attribute names of your data?

Comment: Besides the stage creation have you also created an AWS policy to allow operations on that bucket? See this [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-aws-iam-user.html) for more information.

Comment: @MikeWalton I have updated column names in post as it was my copy paste error. I am unable to view the actual parquet file but I have added a sample record from csv file is converted into the parquet using `>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pyarrow
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
>>> df.to_parquet('file_name.parquet')`

Comment: Did you try same file by placing in your snowflake stage  using put command.See what could be difference ?That may be lead you some conclusions.

Comment: @300 Have you tried running just a `SELECT $1...` without anything else from that file?  Based on the record count, I do not think this has anything to do with access control or where the file is located, since it appears that Snowflake is reading the file.  I'd be interested in the results of this select, which should be a JSON string, I think.

Comment: Thank you @Anand. Doing a PUT to move the parquet file to snowflake internal stage shows the data in the format I have added in my quest.
Thank you @MikeWalton. I have updated my question with the result of `SELECT $1` from stage.

Comment: @300 2 questions for you. #1 - is there a reason that your CSV file is being converted to Parquet?  It'd be faster to just load the CSV file.  #2 - what Parquet format is that because it doesn't look like a standard Parquet format.  When selecting the data as you are with Parquet format selected, it should look much more like a JSON document.  This is likely why you are just getting NULL values for everything.  Those attributes don't exist in your variant output at all.

Comment: @MikeWalton For #1: Our csv files can be quite large (in GB) and primary purpose is to reduce size. #2 I am converting csv to parquet using pandas & pyarrow. And per pandas documentation it "Writes a DataFrame to the binary parquet format." So I think it's binary parquet format. This is how I am converting csv to parquet: `>>> import pandas as pd >>> import pyarrow >>> df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv') >>> df.to_parquet('file_name.parquet')`

Comment: @Sergiu I did confirm with our AWS admin that AWS policy is created and assigned to user id. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: I just noticed that you created the stage with filename it it. It should only be a path like **url = 's3://bucket_name/** and then when you SELECT you specify the filename like **SELECT $1:col_1::BIGINT, $1:col_2::VARCHAR(100), $1:col_3::TIMESTAMP, $1:col_4::VARCHAR(10), $1:col_5::DATE, $1:col_6::BIGINT, $1:col_7::TIMESTAMP, $1:col_8::VARCHAR FROM @STAGE_NAME/file_name.parquet**

Comment: @300 you'd be far better off leaving the files in CSV...creating them in chunks...and then gzip them.  The size might be a little larger, but they will load into Snowflake A LOT faster and easier.

Comment: Also, if the data is already in Pandas, you could just use the python connector to load that data directly into Snowflake.  There are functions in Snowflake's connector that handles that efficiently for you.

Comment: Thank you @Sergiu. I have corrected it. Also I got it working as I found I was missing to provide delimiter while reading csv and converting to data frame. `df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', sep='\t')`
@MikeWalton I'll try both of your suggestions and will see which one works faster. I'll search for functions you referred that would help me load data from pandas data frame to snowflake directly. Thank you so much for both of your valuable inputs and time.